# Enviar text pelo routes (children)

Tags: javascript, angular

Eu envio o title assim:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
  Route.withShell([
    {
      path: 'ex',
      component: exemple,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: exComponent,
          data: {
            title: extract('ex.PAGE_TITLE')
          },...
```

Tem alguma forma de enviar um text pra colocar no meu breadcrumb tbm?

No header ts eu faço:

```
  import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    ....
      constructor(
    private titleService: Title

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  get title(): string {
    return this.titleService.getTitle();
  }
```

e no header.html:

```
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">{{title}}</li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" > <a (click)="add()">{{text}}</a></li>
      </ol>
```

ai gostaria de enviar um text pra ele também, alem do title, para usar globalmente no projeto

Comment: Você poderia enviar um outro parâmetro além do `title` dentro de `data` e efetuar a leitura da mesma forma que o `title`. Não seria esta sua dúvida?

Comment: @MarceloVismari a minha duvida é como conseguir pegar ese outro dado

Answer (score 0):

Adicione na configuração da rotas as informações exatamente como o `title`:

```
// (...)
path: '/',
component: MyPageComponent,
data: {
    title: 'Meu titulo',
    outraInfo: 'teste'
}
// (...)
```

Exemplo de como efetuar a leitura do `title` e `outraInfo`:

```
// (...)
constructor(private router: Router,
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private titleService: Title) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
        .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .pipe(map(() => this.activatedRoute))
        .pipe(map(route => {
            while (route.firstChild) {
                route = route.firstChild;
            }

            return route;
        }))
        .pipe(switchMap(route => route.data))
        .subscribe(event => {
            console.log(event);
            this.titleService.setTitle(event.title);
            // Resultado no console: {title: "Meu titulo", outraInfo: "teste"}
        });
}
// (...)
```

Comment: funcionou, mas quando envio o outraInfo tem que ir o dado que ta em pt-BR.json, que coloco assim: ''DOCS.ADD_TAX_COUPON.TITLE' , mas la ta mostrando exatamente essa string, e nao esse dado. E logo quando inicia nao mostra, só mostra se eu navegar entre as telas e voltar pra ele

Comment: @Maria já tentou utilizar o `translatePipe` direto no template? Imagino que está utilizando o `ngx-translate`, então deixe no template algo do tipo `{{title | translate}}` e no `AppComponent` alimente a variável `title` conforme o exemplo acima. A mesma regra para o `outraInfo`. Seria isto?